# Creación de usuarios Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Utilizo la instrucción

```
useradd -m dummy
```

para que me cree un usuario dummy con el esqueleto que está en /etc/skel. Según he visto, esa carpeta está vacía y se puede añadir directorios y demás. Añado los  directorios y doy permisos 700 para el usuario y demás.

Cuando ejecuto la instrucción, me salta el siguiente warning:

```
Creando el fichero del buzón de correo: El fichero ya existe
```

No sé a qué se debe, no hay ninguna carpeta de ese tipo en mi /skel. Lo adjunto.

```
.bash_logout   .bashrc    Desktop     .gnome2   .mozilla  Videos ..  .bash_profile  Descargas  Documentos  Imagenes  Música
```

Aparte de esto, me gustaría saber si existe algún tipo de plantilla de un usuario normal de sistema. No se me ocurren qué directorios deberían existir en el skel.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque debería ir a serverfault.com o superuser.com

Comment: @Peregring-lk las preguntas tipo serverfault.com son validas aqui. como se menciona en http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/166/2027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error te dice que ,en algún momento del pasado, **ya existió** un usuario con ese nombre.

Mas concretamente, te avisa de que existe un *buzón de correo* en el directorio configurado al efecto, normalmente

> /var/mail
>
> /var/spool/mail

Deberías de borrar ese archivo para que no te muestre más el mensaje.

Otra cosa: el directorio `/etc/skel` suele estar poblado con archivo **ocultos** (cuyo nombre comienza con un **punto** (.)). Es muy raro que esté vacío. Puedes listar su contenido haciendo

```
ls -a /etc/skel
```

Comment: Vale, ya me ha quedado claro el por qué de ese warning. Sobre lo del `ls -a` ya me di cuenta a la hora de "definir" los directorios del esqueleto del usuario.

Comment: Ok. Ahí se suelen colocar los archivos de inicio de la shell y otras cosillas asi. Nunca he visto directorios ahí, la verdad.

Comment: Pues... no sé. Yo he hecho la creación de directorios con `mkdir`, se lo ha tragado y cuando creo el usuario me lo hace con esas carpetas. Lo que no sé es si hay un estándar de directorios de usuario del sistema.

Comment: En Debian, Ubuntu, Slackware (y alguna otra más, que no me acuerdo), no recuerdo nunca ningún directorio ahí (tampoco es que lo mirara mucho). Casi seguro que queda a 'discreción del administrador'. Ahora se está imponiendo el directorio `$HOME/.config` para las configuraciones, por lo que si tendrá mas sentido colocar algún directorio.

Comment: De todas formas, lo paquetes pueden colocar archivos donde quieran. Tal vez algún paquete de alguna aplicación cree directorios ahí, no lo se.

Comment: El directorio `.config` tiene un archivo que se llama user-dirs.dirs que tiene los directorios del usuario. Pero no sé si es posible usarlo para que cuando cree un usuario con useradd, lo haga con esas carpetas. Si cojo el skel por defecto usa las carpetas que yo le asigné. Pero, si no hubiera añadido nada, lo crea prácticamente vacío salvo por los archivos ocultos.

Comment: En mi sistema, ese archivo se copia de la plantilla en `/etc/xdg`. Hay varias páginas de manual: `xdg-user-dir`, `user-dirs.dirs`, `user-dirs.conf`, y algunos más.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación del comando (en Centos 6.7) dice esto:

> CONFIGURATION
>
> The following configuration variables in /etc/login.defs change the behavior of this tool:

Y ahí hace referencia a las variables que configuran el correo:

> MAIL_DIR (string)
>
> The mail spool directory. This is needed to manipulate the mailbox when its corresponding user account is modified or deleted. If not specified, a compile-time default is used.
>
> MAIL_FILE (string)
>
> Defines the location of the users mail spool files relatively to their home directory.
>
> The MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE variables are used by useradd, usermod, and userdel to create, move, or delete the user's mail spool.
>
> If MAIL_CHECK_ENAB is set to yes, they are also used to define the MAIL environment variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad es que no me fijé bien entonces a la hora de leer la documentación del comando.